# kafka python - Bluemix MessageHub - ConnectionError: socket disconnected

Tags: ibm-cloud, kafka-python, message-hub

I'm using the kafka python client to push messages to Message Hub, but noticed that after a while of running my app that it would stop sending messages to Message Hub.

I then noticed the following in my log files:

```
ConnectionError: socket disconnected
```

I updated my code to add `retries=5`:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
import ssl

sasl_mechanism = 'PLAIN'
security_protocol = 'SASL_SSL'

# Create a new context using system defaults, disable all but TLS1.2
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers = app.config['KAFKA_BROKERS_SASL'],
                         sasl_plain_username = app.config['KAFKA_USERNAME'],
                         sasl_plain_password = app.config['KAFKA_PASSWORD'],
                         security_protocol = security_protocol,
                         ssl_context = context,
                         sasl_mechanism = sasl_mechanism,
                         api_version = (0,10),
                         retries=5)

def send_message(message):

    try:
        producer.send(app.config['KAFKA_TOPIC'], message.encode('utf-8'))

        # FIXME sending seems to be unreliable unless we flush
        producer.flush()
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
```

My code runs from a python flask app.  Every request of a certain type that comes in calls the `send_message()` method.

Here are the relevant log lines from Bluemix.  I may have missed a line or two copying and pasting, but hopefully it is enough to figure out what is happening:

```
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: Authenticated as xxxxx May 15, 2017 8:50:54 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: socket disconnected May 15, 2017 8:50:54 PM
APP/1 Got error produce response on topic-partition TopicPartition(topic='movie_ratings', partition=0), retrying (4 attempts left). Error: ConnectionError: socket disconnectedMay 15, 2017 8:50:54 PM
APP/1 Node 0 connection failed -- refreshing metadata May 15, 2017 8:50:54 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: Authenticated as xxxxxMay 15, 2017 8:50:54 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: socket disconnected May 15, 2017 8:50:54 PM
APP/1 Node 0 connection failed -- refreshing metadata May 15, 2017 8:50:54 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: Authenticated as xxxxx May 15, 2017 8:50:54 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: socket disconnected May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 Node 0 connection failed -- refreshing metadata May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 Got error produce response on topic-partition TopicPartition(topic='movie_ratings', partition=0), retrying (2 attempts left). Error: ConnectionError: socket disconnected May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: Authenticated as xxxxx May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: socket disconnected May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 Node 0 connection failed -- refreshing metadata May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 Got error produce response on topic-partition TopicPartition(topic='movie_ratings', partition=0), retrying (1 attempts left). Error: ConnectionError: socket disconnected May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: Authenticated as xxxxx May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: socket disconnected May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 Got error produce response on topic-partition TopicPartition(topic='movie_ratings', partition=0), retrying (0 attempts left). Error: ConnectionError: socket disconnected May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 Node 0 connection failed -- refreshing metadata May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 <BrokerConnection host=kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/23.246.202.51 port=9093>: Authenticated as xxxxx May 15, 2017 8:50:55 PM
APP/1 Node 0 connection failed -- refreshing metadata May 15, 2017 8:50:56 PM
APP/1 ConnectionError: socket disconnected May 15, 2017 8:50:56 PM
APP/1 Unable to import 'sasl'. Fallback to 'puresasl'. May 15, 2017 8:51:00 PM
APP/1 Closing active operation May 15, 2017 8:51:01 PM
```

My topic exists.  My full client code is here: https://github.com/snowch/movie-recommender-demo/blob/effc981cc9f799c41952719619f693172eebcd6a/web_app/app/messagehub_client.py

Any pointers most appreciated ...

Comment: @chris.snow upgrade your Kafka python from 1.3.1 to something newer such as 1.3.3. They fixed a major sasl bug in PR https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/pull/1003 that was causing this I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Dominic's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6827538/dominic-evans) comment, upgrading kafka python to 1.3.3 fixed the issue for me.